# Loop Repeating Twice

Tags: javascript, loops

Im wrecking my brain trying to figure out why this is `map` is repeating twice.

```
let toolbars = toolbarState.map(( toolbarEntry, i ) => {
    let curToolbar = toolbarState.keyOf( toolbarEntry );  // returns the key of the property
    let customProps = {};
    switch( curToolbar ){
    case( "temSelectionCtrl" ):
    case( "functionalCtrl" ):
    case( "referenceCtrl" ):
        return( // returns react component
            <CtrlParent eachToolbar = { toolbarEntry }
                            svgState = { svgState }
                            customProps = { customProps }
                            key = { i }/>
        );
    case( "operationalCtrl" ):
        customProps = {
            enableZoomIn,
            enableZoomOut,
            dispatchEnableZoom
        };
        return (
            <CtrlParent eachToolbar = { toolbarEntry }
                            svgState = { svgState }
                            customProps = { customProps }
                            key = { i }/>
        );
    }
});
```

To clarify, Im using `immutableJs` libary. Which has a method for reading the `key` of a `value`.
Also, the structure of the toolbarState looks like this:

```
toolbarState : {
 temSelectionCtrl: {...},
 functionalCtrl: {...},
 operationalCtrl: {...},
 referenceCtrl: {...}
}
```

Comment: What is `toolbarState.length`

Comment: What exactly is `toolbarState`? `Array.prototype` does not have a function `keyOf`.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, this is part of the code. Im using `immutableJs` library. Amending the question to answer all the questions here.

Comment: to start, have you made sure the calling code isn't repeating twice?

Comment: no its not being called twice :)

Comment: Please clarify: the `map` is being *called* twice and is running once each time, or its being called *once* and is running twice?

Comment: Its being called only once & running twice.

Comment: You'll need to show a [mcve]. There's nothing in the code that would explain the problem, unless Immutable.js has some seriously broken implementation of `.map` which is unlikely.

Comment: @JJJ fair comment. Apologies to all for such a rushed question.